# spring-data pagination and sorting

Tags: pagination, spring-data

I have a question for the Pagination and Sorting of the spring-data project. I like so much this project.

The function `findAll()` returns all the Database Table. It's possible implement a function with  `Page<T> page findAll(SearchObject <T>, Pageable pageable)`, the `SearchObject` with the filters.

I read in the SpringDataa Book one example like this: `Page<Customer> findByLastName(String lastname, Pageable pageable)` if i need a Advanced Search, Is the solution QueryDSL?

Thanks for you time. ;)

Comment: Define "advanced".

Comment: Start here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation. This question lacks specificity; if you had model(s) and a "question" to ask of the data, we could help. But the documentation will answer your question here.

Comment: advanced = for any property of the class, for example Person. findByName or findByLastName or findByNameAndLastname.... I know this is possible, but I want to optimize code and create a Unique "Advanced Search"